# Blender on a web server to generate pictures for a configurator

Tags: python

I am just at developing a house configurator. The first simple part is finished, creating a PDF showing all selections.
The next task is to create pictures. All the information about the configuration is in a query string.
For example:

https://configurator.gemini-next-generation.house/?ba_hb=hb_2_1400_480&ba_chest_n=chest&ba_chest_s=chest&ba_to=simple&ba_tub=simple&ba_wm=NABO_WM_1511_SLIM&br_bed=bed180x200&br_chest=chest&ha_war=wa240&ki_block=block230&ki_chest=chest&ki_ref=NABO_KGN_3471&lr_me=chest&lr_mw=chest&lr_we=swf120&lr_ww=swf120&to_hb=small&to_to=simple

Configurator for GEMINI next generation house
Configure your future home from empty house to fully equipped with furniture, heated garage, ice and snow free sidewalks and driveway.

There will be in future much more parameters about surfaces, also camera position and look at.

The server is best equipped for the task: 6 RTX 3080 graphic cards.

Blender and the most objects should be all time loaded for not loosing time.

Now is the big question about the interface:

The server receives a picture request and how can Python in Blender receive this request?
When Python receives the request, the script will place all the objects,
start rendering and return the picture to the client.

So how could be the communication between the web server software and the Python script in Blender?

Comment: Looks like an interesting and ambitious project. Once working, I imagine the results will be impressive. If it were me I would probably hire a Python developer who is versed in Blender, at least to get the foundation up and running. I'm curious, how much of the Python script have you written so far? (I mean for generating 3D mesh data, etc.)

Comment: Hi. This site is focused on questions about using Blender from an end user point of view. This question seems to be about coding and software development, which are out of scope here. It also seems to be too broad to be easily answered in a Q&A format, bordering on a full time job assignment, since this most likely will be a non trivial development job.